# Pandas better way for Sorting, Grouping, Summing

Tags: python, pandas

New to Pandas so wondering if there is a more Pandithic (coining it!) way to sort some data, group it, and then sum part of it.  The problem is to find the 3 largest values in a series of values and then sum only them.

census_cp is a dataframe with information about counties of states. My current solution is:

```
cen_sort = census_cp.groupby('STNAME').head(3)
cen_sort = cen_sort.groupby('STNAME').sum().sort_values(by='CENSUS2010POP', ascending=False).head(n=3)
cen_sort = cen_sort.reset_index()
print(cen_sort['STNAME'].values.tolist())
```

Im specifically curious if there is a better way to do this as well as why i cant put the sum at the end of the previous line and chain together what seems to me to be obviously connected items (get the top 3 of each and add them together).

Comment: Are values sorted first and by `.head(3)` need top `3` values per group?

Comment: The technical term is 'Pandaren', of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydattotal_seca.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) first with `groupby` and then [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
df = census_cp.groupby('STNAME')
              .apply(lambda x: x.head(3).sum(numeric_only=True))
              .reset_index()
              .nlargest(3, 'CENSUS2010POP')
```

Sample:

```
census_cp = pd.DataFrame({'STNAME':list('abscscbcdbcsscae'),
                   'CENSUS2010POP':[4,5,6,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,3,6,5]})

print (census_cp)
    CENSUS2010POP STNAME
0               4      a
1               5      b
2               6      s
3               5      c
4               6      s
5               2      c
6               3      b
7               4      c
8               5      d
9               6      b
10              4      c
11              5      s
12              4      s
13              3      c
14              6      a
15              5      e


df = census_cp.groupby('STNAME') \
              .apply(lambda x: x.head(3).sum(numeric_only=True)) \
              .reset_index() \
              .nlargest(3, 'CENSUS2010POP')
print (df)
  STNAME  CENSUS2010POP
5      s             17
1      b             14
2      c             11
```

If need double top `3` [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) per groups and then [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) of summed values use:

```
df1 = census_cp.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP']
               .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum())
               .nlargest(3)
               .reset_index()
print (df1)
  STNAME  CENSUS2010POP
0      s             17
1      b             14
2      c             13
```

Or:

```
df1 = census_cp.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].nlargest(3)
               .groupby(level=0)
               .sum()
               .nlargest(3)
               .reset_index() 
print (df1)
  STNAME  CENSUS2010POP
0      s             17
1      b             14
2      c             13
```

Comment: Love the nlargest.  Curious about putting the different operations on separate lines.  Is that preferred syntax in pandas or did you just do it for legibility?  Also is the '\' needed at the end of each command?

Comment: No, \ is only for long lines in python code. If are omited python sometimes return error. But is possible use only one line code, but then it is less readable.